# angular get json from server but cannot display columns only whole model

Tags: json, django, angularjs

So my problem is i can access json data from server but i dont know how to display them properly, until now i can only display all model and i would like to display only some data.

My template

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
 
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
{% verbatim %}

<body ng-app="MyApp">

<div ng-controller="MyPerson">

        <div ng-repeat="person in person">

        <p>{{person}}</p>
            <p>{{persons.city}}</p>
            <p>{{person.city}}</p>
            <p>{{person.id}}</p>
            <script>


var MyApp = angular.module('MyApp', []);

MyApp.controller('MyPerson', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/people/person/?format=json').
        success(function(personData) {
            $scope.person = personData;
        });
        });

            </script>

            </div>
    </div>

{% endverbatim %}


</body>
</html>
```

My urls

```js
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from people.views import *
from django.contrib import admin
from people.api import PersonResource
from tastypie.api import Api
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


person_resource = PersonResource()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='home'),
url(r'^first/$', FirstView.as_view(), name='first'),
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^people/', include(person_resource.urls)),


)
```

My api

```js
from people.models import Person
from tastypie.resources import ModelResource





class PersonResource(ModelResource):
    """
    API Facet
    """
    class Meta:
        queryset = Person.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'person'
```

My model

```js
from django.db import models


class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('Person', blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```

on terminal i get

```js
[10/Dec/2014 18:38:20] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 797
[10/Dec/2014 18:38:20] "GET /people/person/?format=json HTTP/1.1" 200 420
```

and my html is

```js
{"limit":20,"next":null,"offset":0,"previous":null,"total_count":3}

[{"city":"Budapest","id":1,"name":"Igor","resource_uri":"/people/job/person/1/","slug":"person"},{"city":"Warszawa","id":2,"name":"Karol","resource_uri":"/people/job/person/2/","slug":"person1"},{"city":"Jerozolima","id":3,"name":"Michal","resource_uri":"/people/job/person/3/","slug":"Ima"}]
```

So i can access json but it works only when i make ng-repeat person in persons
but then it only display data in these {{person}} 
if i add sth else for example {{person.name}} it display nothing. I would like to display everything in nice format. I work on django and use rest Tastypie

Comment: ng-repeat="person in person" <<<< same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your JSON from `http://127.0.0.1:8000/people/person/?format=json` is coming back as an array then you need to change your `$scope.person` to be `$scope.persons` and your ng-repeat needs to read `person in persons`.

Comment: when i request http /people/person/1/ i can display {{person.name}} and etc but when i go back to people/person and want to do ng-repeat it;s not working, ng-repeat only with this {{person}} but then everything looks like clear json data, what i am doing wrong? can it be sth with json data? or wrong angular tags?